# How to show that $E(X\mid X>y) = \frac{\int_y^\infty x g(x) dx}{1 - F(y)} $ for the truncated expectation of a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I would like to show that if $X$ has pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$, then the expectation of $X$ conditional on $X$ being greater than some value $y$ is given on wikipedia as:

$$
E(X\mid X>y) = \frac{\int_y^\infty x g(x) \, dx}{1 - F(y)} 
$$

I am wondering how to derive this directly. I have the following:

$$
E(X\mid X>y) = \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} x f(x\mid X>y) \, dy
$$

However, I am not sure how to take care of the $x>y$ part in $f(x\mid X>y)$. It should be:

$$
f(x\mid X>y) = \frac{f(x,X>y)}{f(x>y)}
$$

But this doesn't make sense as a probability statement. Am I supposed to use indicators here?

Comment: Where you wrote $$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X>y) = \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} x f(x\mid x>y) \, dy,$$it ought to say $$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X>y) = \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} x f(x\mid X>y) \, dy$$

Comment: I've fixed it. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't know what $f(x>y)$ means, but where you wrote that you need $\Pr(X>y)$ (where I am careful to use a capital $X$ and a lower-case $y. \qquad$

Comment: Using the same notation, $f$, for several different things is abominable, and too often seen. One can reasonably write $f_X(x)$ and $f_{X>y}(x)$, and then the $f$ doesn't mean several different things. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am not sure how to take care of the $x>y$ part in $f(x|x>y)$. It should be:  $$f(x|x>y) = \frac{f(x,x>y)}{f(x>y)}$$

Capitalisation is not optional.   The meaning attached to these letters is *case sensitive*.   $X$ is a random variable, and $x$ and $y$ are values it *may* realise.

So, applying Bayes' Rule to mixed probability density and mass functions:

$$\begin{align}f_X(x\mid X>y) ~&=~ \frac{f_X(x)\,\mathsf P(X>y\mid X=x)}{\mathsf P(X>y)} \\[1ex] &=~ \frac{f_X(x)~\mathbf 1_{x>y}}{1-F_X(y)}\end{align}$$

---

Additionally if $g(\;)$ is the given probability density function of $X$ we  should not be suddenly using $f(\;)$ for that ... unless $g$ was a typo.   So, anyway, using the original letters:

$$g(x\mid X>y) ~=~ \dfrac {g(x)~\mathbf 1_{x>y}}{1-F(y)}$$

Comment: Can I ask how you got $P(X>y\mid X=x) = 1_{x>y}$?

Comment: If $x$ is greater than $y$, then $X$ is *certainly* greater than $y$ when given that $X$ is $x$.  If $x$ is *not* greater than $y$ then it is *impossible* for $X$ to be greater than $y$ when $X$ is $x$. $$\begin{align}\therefore\qquad\mathsf P(X>y\mid X=x) ~&=~ \begin{cases}1 &:& x>y \\ 0 &:& \text{else}\end{cases}\\[1ex] &=~ \mathbf 1_{x>y}\end{align}$$

Comment: Rather than $\text{“}f_X(x\mid X>y)\text{'',}$ one ought to write $f_{X>y}(x). \qquad$

Comment: No, one ought not.

Answer (score 1):

Let the CDF of $X$ conditioned on $X > y$ be $F(X\mid X > y)$. We have for any $x > y$ that
$$
F(X < x \mid X > y) = \frac{F(y < X < x)}{F(X > y)} = \frac{F(x) - F(y)}{1 - F(y)}
$$
Then
$$
f(X\mid X > y) = F'(X < x \mid X > y) = (\frac{F(x) - F(y)}{1 - F(y)})' = \frac{f(x)}{1 - F(y)}
$$
for $x > y$.

Answer (score 1):

First we have
$$
\operatorname{E}(X\mid X>y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X>y}(x)\,dx.
$$
After that it is enough to show that
$$
f_{X>y}(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{f_X(x)}{\Pr(X>y)} & \text{if } x>y, \\[8pt] 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
To show that, it is enought to show that for every measurable set $A$ of real numbers we have
$$
\Pr(X\in A\mid X>y) = \int_{\large A \,\cap\, (y,\infty)} \frac{f_X(x)}{\Pr(X>y)} \, dx. \tag a
$$
We know that
$$
\underbrace{ \Pr(X\in A\mid X>y) = \frac{\Pr(X\in A\cap (y,\infty)) }{\Pr(X>y)} }_\text{definition of conditional probability}\  \underbrace{ = \frac{ \displaystyle \int_{\large A \,\cap\, (y,\infty)} f_X(x)\,dx }{\Pr(X>y)} }_\text{definition of density}
$$
and that last fraction is clearly equal to $(\textbf{a}).$